# Non-Reference Loss Function

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, image-enhancement

I was going through this awesome research paper and I have found the term Non-Reference Loss Functions. Can someone help me to understand what it is? Some resource link is more than enough, I have googled this and I have found no clue.

What is this **Non-Reference loss function and how they are training a model without paired or unpaired data**?
[Paper PDF](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/html/Guo_Zero-Reference_Deep_Curve_Estimation_for_Low-Light_Image_Enhancement_CVPR_2020_paper.html)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, "Non-Reference loss function" is a fancy title for ["Unsupervised learning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning).
The authors of the paper were able to define a loss function (sec. 3.3) that describes how a "good looking image" should look like *without* using a "clean reference" image: The four loss terms they defined compare the output image `Y` to the input image `I` and check that the contrast in `Y` and it's exposure is better than `I`, yet boundaries, colorness and spatial consistency remains.

By defining a loss function that does not requires a "ground truth" image allows the authors to train their model on "corrupt" images only - which are much easier to come by.